# Shifting letters after converting user input to be appropriate for cipher

Tags: python, encryption, shift

I'm not the best with python and am trying to cipher shift text entered by the user. The way this cipher should work is disregarding symbols, numbers, etc. It also converts full stops to X's and must all be upper case. I currently have the code for that but am unsure as to how to take that converted text and shift it by a number given by the user. Not sure if this all makes sense, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
def convert_to_Caesar(t):
      
    #Remove all special characters and only show A-Z
    t = re.sub("[^A-Za-z.]",'', t)
    cipherText = ""
    # Full stops are replaced with X's
    for letter in t:
        if letter == '.':
            cipherText += 'X'
    # Lower case is converted to upper case
    
        else: 
            cipherText += letter.upper()
    # Plain text is ciphered and returned
    
    return cipherText


    

# User enters plain text to cipher
text = input("What do you want to cipher? ")
shift = int(input("How many positions to shift by? "))

print(convert_to_Caesar(text))
```

Thank you

Comment: Why not use the ASCII codes by ord,chr?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ord()/chr() as suggested by @Girish Srivatsa:

```
alphabet_len = ord('Z') - ord('A') + 1
new_letter = chr((ord(letter.upper()) - ord('A') + shift) % alphabet_len + ord('A'))
```

But it might be cleaner if you just create a variable that holds your alphabet:

```
import string
alphabet = "".join(list(string.ascii_uppercase))
```

Then you look what you look up the position in your alphabet, add the positions, then look up what the new letter is:

```
pos = alphabet.find(letter.upper())
if pos == -1:
  if letter == '.':
     new_letter = 'X'
  else:
     # discard other symbols
     new_letter = ''
else:
  new_pos = (pos + shift) % len(alphabet)      
  new_letter = alphabet[new_pos]
```

Note, you cannot tell if 'X' in your cipher text a shifted letter or '.'.  If you need to fix that, add '.' to your alphabet and remove the special case for '.' under `if pos == -1`.  This becomes messy with chr()/ord() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be formatted even more correctly, following all your rules but formatting in capitals and lowercase too. This shifts the dictionary, and runs if loops. I know you asked for all letters to be capitals, but this improves the code a little.

Output of Code:

```
Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? 1
This must be encoded! Please, Work!
5
Ymnx rzxy gj jshtiji! Uqjfxj, Btwp!
```

Code:

```
import time
def shift_dict(Caesar, Shift):
  dic_len = len(Caesar)
  Shift = Shift % dic_len
  list_dic = [(k,v) for k, v in iter(Caesar.items())]
  Shifted = {
    list_dic[x][0]: list_dic[(x - Shift) % dic_len][1]
    for x in range(dic_len)
  }
  return Shifted
def shift_dict2(Caesar, Shift):
  dic_len = len(Caesar)
  Shift = Shift % dic_len
  list_dic = [(k,v) for k, v in iter(Caesar.items())]
  Shifted = {
    list_dic[x][0]: list_dic[(x - Shift) % dic_len][-1]
    for x in range(dic_len)
  }
  return Shifted

UpperList = {
  "A":0,
  "B":1,
  "C":2,
  "D":3,
  "E":4,
  "F":5,
  "G":6,
  "H":7,
  "I":8,
  "J":9,
  "K":10,
  "L":11,
  "M":12,
  "N":13,
  "O":14,
  "P":15,
  "Q":16,
  "R":17,
  "S":18,
  "T":19,
  "U":20,
  "V":21,
  "W":22,
  "X":23,
  "Y":24,
  "Z":25
}
UpperCaesar = {
  "A":"A",
  "B":"B",
  "C":"C",
  "D":"D",
  "E":"E",
  "F":"F",
  "G":"G",
  "H":"H",
  "I":"I",
  "J":"J",
  "K":"K",
  "L":"L",
  "M":"M",
  "N":"N",
  "O":"O",
  "P":"P",
  "Q":"Q",
  "R":"R",
  "S":"S",
  "T":"T",
  "U":"U",
  "V":"V",
  "W":"W",
  "X":"X",
  "Y":"Y",
  "Z":"Z"
}
LowerList = {
  "a":0,
  "b":1,
  "c":2,
  "d":3,
  "e":4,
  "f":5,
  "g":6,
  "h":7,
  "i":8,
  "j":9,
  "k":10,
  "l":11,
  "m":12,
  "n":13,
  "o":14,
  "p":15,
  "q":16,
  "r":17,
  "s":18,
  "t":19,
  "u":20,
  "v":21,
  "w":22,
  "x":23,
  "y":24,
  "z":25

}
LowerCaesar = {
  "a":"a",
  "b":"b",
  "c":"c",
  "d":"d",
  "e":"e",
  "f":"f",
  "g":"g",
  "h":"h",
  "i":"i",
  "j":"j",
  "k":"k",
  "l":"l",
  "m":"m",
  "n":"n",
  "o":"o",
  "p":"p",
  "q":"q",
  "r":"r",
  "s":"s",
  "t":"t",
  "u":"u",
  "v":"v",
  "w":"w",
  "x":"x",
  "y":"y",
  "z":"z"
}
UpperList1 = {
  "A":0,
  "B":1,
  "C":2,
  "D":3,
  "E":4,
  "F":5,
  "G":6,
  "H":7,
  "I":8,
  "J":9,
  "K":10,
  "L":11,
  "M":12,
  "N":13,
  "O":14,
  "P":15,
  "Q":16,
  "R":17,
  "S":18,
  "T":19,
  "U":20,
  "V":21,
  "W":22,
  "X":23,
  "Y":24,
  "Z":25
}
UpperCaesar1 = {
  "A":"A",
  "B":"B",
  "C":"C",
  "D":"D",
  "E":"E",
  "F":"F",
  "G":"G",
  "H":"H",
  "I":"I",
  "J":"J",
  "K":"K",
  "L":"L",
  "M":"M",
  "N":"N",
  "O":"O",
  "P":"P",
  "Q":"Q",
  "R":"R",
  "S":"S",
  "T":"T",
  "U":"U",
  "V":"V",
  "W":"W",
  "X":"X",
  "Y":"Y",
  "Z":"Z"
}
LowerList1 = {
  "a":0,
  "b":1,
  "c":2,
  "d":3,
  "e":4,
  "f":5,
  "g":6,
  "h":7,
  "i":8,
  "j":9,
  "k":10,
  "l":11,
  "m":12,
  "n":13,
  "o":14,
  "p":15,
  "q":16,
  "r":17,
  "s":18,
  "t":19,
  "u":20,
  "v":21,
  "w":22,
  "x":23,
  "y":24,
  "z":25

}
LowerCaesar1 = {
  "a":"a",
  "b":"b",
  "c":"c",
  "d":"d",
  "e":"e",
  "f":"f",
  "g":"g",
  "h":"h",
  "i":"i",
  "j":"j",
  "k":"k",
  "l":"l",
  "m":"m",
  "n":"n",
  "o":"o",
  "p":"p",
  "q":"q",
  "r":"r",
  "s":"s",
  "t":"t",
  "u":"u",
  "v":"v",
  "w":"w",
  "x":"x",
  "y":"y",
  "z":"z"
}

Asker = int(input("Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? "))

if Asker == 1:
  Plaintext = str(input(""))
  OriginalShift = int(input(""))
  Shift = OriginalShift*-1
  UpperCaesar = shift_dict(UpperCaesar, Shift)
  LowerCaesar = shift_dict(LowerCaesar, Shift)
  Lister = []
  X = 0
  for i in range(len(Plaintext)):
    if Plaintext[X].isalpha():
      if Plaintext[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(UpperCaesar[Plaintext[X]])
      else:
        Lister.append(LowerCaesar[Plaintext[X]])
    else:
      Lister.append(Plaintext[X])
    X += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
elif Asker == 2:
  Asker1 = int(input("Do you have the key (1), or not(2): "))
  if Asker1 == 1: 
    Plaintext = str(input(""))
    OriginalShift = int(input(""))
    Shift = OriginalShift*-1
    UpperCaesar = shift_dict(UpperCaesar, 26 - Shift)
    LowerCaesar = shift_dict(LowerCaesar, 26 - Shift)
    Lister = []
    X = 0
    for i in range(len(Plaintext)):
      if Plaintext[X].isalpha():
        if Plaintext[X].isupper():
          Lister.append(UpperCaesar[Plaintext[X]])
        else:
          Lister.append(LowerCaesar[Plaintext[X]])
      else:
        Lister.append(Plaintext[X])
      X += 1
    print(*Lister, sep = "")
  elif Asker1 == 2:
    Plaintext = str(input(""))
    OriginalShift = 0
    for i in range(26):
      UpperCaesar = shift_dict2(UpperCaesar, -1)
      LowerCaesar = shift_dict2(LowerCaesar, -1)
      Lister = []
      X = 0
      for i in range(len(Plaintext)):
        if Plaintext[X].isalpha():
          if Plaintext[X].isupper():
            Lister.append(UpperCaesar[Plaintext[X]])
          else:
            Lister.append(LowerCaesar[Plaintext[X]])
        else:
          Lister.append(Plaintext[X])
        X += 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
      print("With a shift of ", 25 - (OriginalShift*-1), ": ", *Lister, sep = "")
      OriginalShift -= 1
```